# Sequence with infinite number of zeros

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

My question reads:

Let’s call a sequence $(x_n)$ zero-heavy if there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n$ satisfying $N\leq\ n\leq\ N + M$ where $x_n = 0$.

If a sequence is zero-heavy does it necessarily contain an inﬁnite number of zeros?

Now, I have decided that this is true, but I am not too sure how to phrase my reasoning correctly. I do not necessarily want to write out a proof as I want to just argue with direct reasoning. I was thinking along the lines of well if we know it is zero dense, then we can always find a $0$ in between the interval given. Then because this happens for all $N$ in a way the intervals continue infinitely then so do the $0$'s.

I am not too sure if I am making too much sense but I do have a sense of what is going on in this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Every interval of length $M+1$ has one, and there are infinitely many such intervals with no intersection.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, okay this is what I was trying to get too but I was not too sure how to say that because we have infinite many intervals then we have infinite many places where a 0 must be

Comment: Yes, infinite many disjoint places where you know there is a $0$. Doesn't that give what you want?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, because none of the intervals overlap then we continuously get new places where a 0 is so we have an infinite number of 0s.

Comment: Suppose there exists a finite number of zeros. Then, let $A:=\sup\{r\mid x_r=0\}$. Since the set of zeros is finite, $A$ exists (and $\in\Bbb N$). Now, applyling the problem hypothesis on $A+1$, we have $\exists M\in\Bbb N$ such that $\exists n\in\Bbb N$ satisfying $A+1\leq n\leq A+M+1$ and $x_n=0$ but we have $n\gt A$ contradicting $A$ being the supremum of the index of the zeros.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Just for your first comment, you are saying the for every M we can find M+1 terms where at least one 0 is contained?

Comment: @Sam: No.  You have a particular M, as you stated in the definition.  And you don't "find" M+1 terms, the definition you stated says that every consecutive M+1 terms has a 0. Think more about the definition, e.g. with M=4.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would start:

Consider the subsequences $x_{k(M+1)},\cdots,x_{(k+1)(M+1)-1}$, where $k$ is a positive integer.